# iCloud sharing: "You need a newer version of App to open this but the required version couldn't be found in the App Store."

Tags: ios, icloud

What is going on?

How can I workaround it?

[image]

I just started to develop the app. And tried to share ckrecord. Of course there is no version in the app store because I develop it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I forgot to set `CKSharingSupported` to `true` in `info.plist` file.

Comment: OMG, this is evil. Thanks for the hint. I think noone can ever blame you because of "forgetting to set CKSharingSupported", because well ... I did not find any doc about that in advance.

Comment: Just in case it trips anyone else up: `CKSharingSupported`'s Type is Boolean (and its value is `YES`). Thanks Bartłomiej for the fix!